Global Flag Summary userscript is no longer working due to rate-limiting changes
When running the Global Flag Summary userscript, 57 out of the 244 sites it calls to were successful, and the rest produced error status codes. Most produced 404 status codes, but towards the end of running the script, the response code changed from 404 to rate-limited. When I manually tried to access about 20 of the links that were listed as "404"s, they all worked fine.
In addition to the above, running this script also logged me out network-wide and gave me a Cloudfare challenge when I tried to access SE again.
Here is a screenshot of a small section of the errors:

Stack Exchange recently added 3 new rate limits to "prevent unauthorized access to the network," and these changes may be the cause of the new 404/rate-limiting errors.
Could this please be fixed?

How many requests do this script perform? How long does it take?

@A.L for me, since I regularly hang out in Charcoal HQ and flag spam on a bunch of network sites, it is looking for about 244 flag pages (and hence 244 requests). For me it usually takes a few minutes. Definetly over 10 requests per minute.

I would echo A.L's comment. Looking at the implementation, it does appear to include rate limit detection and backoff, but it may not be aligned with the new rate limit. The Meta post introducing the new limits say that scripts will be limited to 60 requests per second. Is this script exceeding 60 requests per second?

@ThomasOwens almost certainly not, unless there are a ton of requests it makes that I don't know about/understand. Floern (script's creator) has been on Meta this week, maybe they'll see this post and be able to provide a better answer...

The workaround is to register for all or most SE sites...

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I think I honestly have gotten to most at this point.  But why would that help? It's giving 404s on sites I have registered for.

I cannot reproduce. I only got a 404 on Math Overflow and its Meta but I went to the site, logged in, and then reloaded the global flag summary and it worked. I have 152 accounts network wide (so, 152 main + 152 meta = 304 requests), so its certainly not less than you which might avoid rate limiting.

If you're reporting that you got logged out during script execution, then it's not really a surprise you started getting 404s. The user flag summary page is only visible if you're logged in. And yeah, as Josh says those would have turned into 429s pretty fast because the script doesn't expect you to get logged out partway through execution, so it wouldn't have had any reason to back off. It then isn't too surprising other people can't reproduce this. We may not even be able to reproduce it ourselves - not sure on this point.

I can see in the traffic history that we got requests from you for user flag histories on a bunch of sites, then it cuts off, and we immediately start returning 404s from your IP address for a logged-out user. I think this is a smoking gun that you got logged out partway through script execution. What logged you out, I don't know. We don't have any automatic logout triggers in the application, at least that I'm aware of. That would be very weird UX. So I suspect either you performed an action that logged you out, or there is a bug unrelated to ratelimiting.

@Slate wow you guys can see the history anytime I view anything on SE...wow...I tested this a few times and each and every time it logged me out network-wide.

@Slate no automatic logout triggers? That can't be right. We've observed that a userscript that ends up making a lot of requests to the network search seems to kill the user session and log you out of the network. This was repeatable. The userscript got patched to only do a search on demand rather than automatically to stop the logout issues. Also, to clarify - that was few months back, not related to the new changes. But may have been related to CloudFlare.

With that said, I tried the Global Flag Statistics 4 times in parallel - opened 4 tabs to the global flags page. And each finished the 304 requests it does successfully. It too a bit longer but that was to be expected.

@VLAZ Strange then that it failed for me. Maybe try again (I was able to reproduce this 10 times in a row, with varying sites failing, and only getting the actual rate-limit sometimes)

@Starship what is your login provider?

What do you mean by that. I use log in with google if thats what you mean? @ShadowWizard

Yeah, so Google is your provider. Next question: when this happens, are you also logged out of Google? e.g. when you go to gmail, or any other Google service you're usually logged into.

@ShadowWizard no I'm logged into google

I'm voting to close this because, as the answer states, this was an ephemeral issue caused by the user getting logged out while the script was running, and thus fits into the close reason "can no longer be reproduced...changes to the [...] circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete". If this issue of getting logged out while running the script recurs repeatedly, please edit this post and we'll reopen it.

Might I ask why you think this wouldn’t potentially happen to someone else in the future @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog

Correlation doesn't imply causation. Unless it can be proven that it's a recurring issue, it's not useful to have reports of random one-offs - that's why the site has a close reason for them.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I think that it can be assumed that I am not the only person that will ever experience this issue, as issues usually affect many people, unless there is reason to believe otherwise. Every bug report isn't required to have multiple people say "think happened" for it to be considered valid.

If you can provide me with a RayID I can verify further but I'm reasonably confident it's not the new changes that came into effect Monday.
The change made on Monday only targets things that are running out of Microsoft Azure. This is the number of times the rule that went into effect Monday, October 7th has triggered:

The rule you've hit rate limits the source if they trigger an excessive number of 404 responses. This rate limit has been in place for at least 8 months if not since the beginning of the Cloudflare migration last year. The rationale behind the rule is that no single source should be requesting pages that don't exist at a high rate. Many malicious bots use this technique to probe the site.
Edit:
Further investigation shows that you were logged out in the middle of the script running which resulted in the 404's. The CDN does not have the ability to log users out.

Might I ask what a RayId is and how I could find it?

@Starship last section of this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/403462/784098

But question is why it gave 404 for pages that actually exist? Ah, it was because OP got logged out while the script was running, so is there auto-logout new feature that is triggered when requesting X pages per minute, perhaps?

Looking through the logs w/ @Slate it does look like the cause was a log out event during the script. The CDN does not have the ability to log users out.

So why was I being logged out, network-wide (even on sites it never tried to access because it was rate-limited) @JoshZhang

@Starship I'm not sure however when investigating this, I was told that getting logged out was a long running known bug. That's would be on the app side which I'm not as knowledgeable on.
